# determinate moment problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, moment-problem

if the moment problem is determinate i.e  given $L(f)= \int_{\mathbb{R}} fd\mu$  then $\mu$ is unique, how can i show that the the space of polynomials with  complex coefficients i.e $C[x]$ is dense in $L^2(\mu)$

Comment: Is this a special case of Proposition 4.15, p. 50 of Simon's [The classical moment problem as a self-adjoint finite difference operator](http://math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/270.pdf#page=50) ?

Answer (score 0):

you can have an elementary proof from  [The classical moment problem and some related questions in analysis, Corollary 2.3.3.](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/akhiezer.pdf)

Comment: Hi all, Thank you so much for the help. That was really helpful.